# How to implement a modified cross entropy loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, cross-entropy

I am currently working on a change detection project for my university course and I was stuck at writing a custom loss function.I know i have to use function closure to be able to use data from layers of the model but i don't know enough tensorflow/keras knowledge to write effecient code.
[The loss function equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FWgT.png)

This is the modified cross entropy loss equation that i'm trying to turn into code.The loss needs the matrix W which I have to calculate using the inputs to the model, that is X1 and X2. So at the moment I have this.

```
def cmg_loss(X1,X2):
    def loss(y_true,y_pred):
        print(X1)
        if X1.shape[0] == None:
            X1 = tf.reshape(X1,(224,224,3))
            X2 = tf.reshape(X2,(224,224,3))
            cmm = [get_cmm(X1,X2)]
        else:
            cmm = [get_cmm(X1[i],X2[i]) for i in range(X1.shape[0])]
            
        N = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true.shape[0],dtype=tf.float32)
        N_val = y_true.shape[0]
        loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(0.0)
        if(N_val == None):
            loss = get_cmgloss(y_true[0],y_pred[0],cmm[0])
            loss = tf.math.multiply(-1.0,loss)
            return tf.math.divide(loss,N)
        
        else:
            for i in range(N_val):
                print(i)
                print("CMM len ", len(cmm))
                x = get_cmgloss(y_true[i],y_pred[i],cmm[i])
                loss = tf.math.add(loss,get_cmgloss(y_true[i],y_pred[i],cmm[i]))
                loss = tf.math.multiply(-1.0,loss)
        return tf.math.divide(loss,N)
    return loss
    
def get_cmgloss(y_true,y_pred,W):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true,dtype=tf.float32)
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
    betaminus = findbetaminus(y_pred)
    betaplus = 1 - betaminus
    betaminus = betaminus.astype('float32')
    betaplus = betaplus.astype('float32')
    loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(0.0)
    N = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true.shape[0] * y_true.shape[0],dtype=tf.float32)
    betaminus_matrix = tf.fill((224,224), betaminus)
    betaplus_matrix = tf.fill((224,224), betaplus)
    one_matrix = tf.fill((224,224), 1.0)

    first_term = tf.math.multiply(betaminus_matrix,tf.math.multiply(y_true,tf.math.log(y_pred)))
    second_term = tf.math.multiply(betaplus_matrix,tf.math.multiply(tf.math.subtract(one_matrix,y_true), tf.math.log(tf.math.subtract(one_matrix,y_pred))))
    sum_first_second = tf.math.add(first_term, second_term)
    prod = tf.math.multiply(W,sum_first_second)
        
    loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(prod)
    #loss = K.sum(K.sum(betaminus_matrix * y_true * tf.math.log(y_pred),betaplus_matrix * (1 - y_true) * tf.math.log(1 - y_pred)))
    loss = tf.math.multiply(-1.0, loss)
    return tf.math.divide(loss,N)
    
def findbetaminus(gt):
    count_1 = tf.math.count_nonzero(gt == 1)
    size = gt.shape[0] * gt.shape[1]
    return count_1 / size;

def get_cmm(x1,x2):
    b1_diff_sq = tf.math.squared_difference(x1[:,:,0],x2[:,:,0])
    b2_diff_sq = tf.math.squared_difference(x1[:,:,1],x2[:,:,1])
    b3_diff_sq = tf.math.squared_difference(x1[:,:,2],x2[:,:,2])
    sum_3bands = tf.math.add(tf.math.add(b1_diff_sq,b2_diff_sq),b3_diff_sq)
    cmm = tf.math.sqrt(sum_3bands)
    #print(cmm)
    
    max_val = tf.reduce_max(cmm)
    #print("MAX_VAL ", max_val)
    max_val_matrix = tf.fill((224,224), max_val)
    cmm_bar = tf.divide(cmm,max_val_matrix)
    #print(cmm_bar)
    
    mean_cmm_bar = tf.reduce_mean(cmm_bar)
    #print("MEAN_VAL ", mean_cmm_bar)
    mean_cmm_bar_matrix = tf.fill((224,224), mean_cmm_bar)
    #print(mean_cmm_bar_matrix)
    condition = tf.math.greater(mean_cmm_bar_matrix, cmm_bar)
    return tf.where(condition, mean_cmm_bar_matrix, cmm_bar)
    #print(weights)
```

It would be great help if you could guide me on how to develop a loss function that makes use of data from other layers and also call multiple functions in its computation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use more advanced loss functions, you will have to use `tf.GradientTape` to do train steps by yourself instead of using the `fit` method.
You can find many examples on the web and in the tensorflow documentation. This requires a little more work but it is much more powerful because you can essentially output a list of tensors out of your custom Model in the call method and then calculate the target losses and choose which parameters are changed.